# Find the area of the shaded section -- solvable without trig?

Tags: geometry

The sides are of length ten. This came from a coworker who got it from a friend overseas, so it's not entirely clear if this actually solvable without trigonometry.

[image]

Here's what I've been able to figure out (with help from Reddit):

[image]

Area 1 is 1/4th of a circle of radius 10, or 25pi.

Area 2 is the area of a square of length 5 (25) minus 1/4th of the circle in the picture (25pi/4), or 25 - 25pi/4.

Area 3, though? No idea.

How can this be best solved?

Comment: If integrals are allowed, I may have a solution, but since you forbid trigonometry I assume you only want basic geometry tools?

Comment: Actually forget it, I took a look at the integral, and I end up with some trig function as a solution...